# Is it possible to get user information about installed apps on react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I've been searching but couldn't find a proper way on how to read the users statistics on installed applications in react native.

I want to get the time when the user last used some other app (e.g. Facebook).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not possible. It's restricted by Apple.

Comment: apple highly refrains you from doing this.. not possible